# Change URL to filter posts

Tags: urls

I am trying to  understand how I can filter posts on a page simply by changing the URL.
I tried adding this just as a test - http://mydomain.com/find-work/?orderby=title&order=ASC which does not change anything (I tried DESC as well). 
I basically want to have some buttons with different URL’s that will change the order of the posts displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have explained a similar trick [over here](http://blog.rutwick.com/use-jquery-to-reorder-your-wp-posts-on-the-fly). You'll have to modify it a bit to suit your need.